# How to assign array string to array object

Tags: java

I have something like this :

```
List<Page> result = new ArrayList<Page>();
```

Page is a class with 3 string variables;

I have an array as such :

```
List<String[]> output = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Which is populated like this in a loop:

```
String[] out = new String[3];   
out[0] = "";
out[1] = "";
out[2] = "";
```

then added to output: `output.set(i, out);`

How can I assign **output** *(type:String)* to **result** *(type:Page)*?

Comment: A `Page` is not a `String[]`. A `String[]` is not a `Page`.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible. Maybe you could give some context as to what you are trying to accomplish and why you think you need to do this to achieve it.

Comment: Can you post the code for your `Page` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are looking for something like this (code requires Java 8 but can be easily rewritten for earlier versions using loop)

```
List<String[]> output = new ArrayList<String[]>();
// populate output with arrays containing three elements 
// which will be used used to initialize Page instances
//...

List<Page> result = output.stream()
                          .map(arr -> new Page(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```